# Redis, the client is closed

Tags: node.js, express, redis

I am trying to implement redis into my nodejs and expressjs API REST, but for some reason I am getting the error `The client is closed`.

1. I´ve installed redis for windows
2. I´ve ran `redis-server` in the cmd.
3. I´ve tested the redis cli by runing `redis-cli` and then passing `ping`. `PONG` was logged as a result, so it is working.

Created a middleware init_redis.js

```
const redis = require('redis');

const createConnectedClient = async () => {
    
        const client = redis.createClient({
            host: 'localhost',
            port:  6379,
        });

        client.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('Redis client error', err);
        });

        await client.connect();

        return client;
};

module.exports = createConnectedClient;
```

I tried to test redis in my server.js

```
const createConnectedClient = require('./middleware/init_redis');

let redisClient;

(async () => {
    try {
        redisClient = await createConnectedClient();
        redisClient.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('Redis client error', err);
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Failed to connect to Redis:', error);
    }
})();

(async () => {
    if (redisClient) {
        try {
            await redisClient.set('foo', 'bar');
            const value = await redisClient.get('foo');
            console.log(value);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error setting or getting key from Redis:', err);
        }
    }
})();
```

When I run my nodejs server, I get `The client is closed`. Why is this happening if my redis server is running and I am connectinc my client?

If I do asynchronous functions to run the client, nothing is being logged in my console.

Comment: You mention you installed Redis for Windows. There are no officially supported versions of Redis for Windows. The ones that are out there are community created and not always consistently updated. So, what version of Redis are you running precisely? I ask because fairly old versions of Redis sometimes won't work with the latest Node Redis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest version of `redis` in npm ( 4.6.13 ), it is documented that the function `createClient` in the Redis package is asynchronous, meaning you must wait for the connection to be established for it to work correctly.

Notice that you call createClient but do not handle the promise nor call `await` on the function call ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#basic-example ).

The line requiring the client (`const redisClient = require('./middleware/init_redis');`) creates the client, then the program attempts to use it immediately after, thus resulting in the error you are getting: `The client is closed`; you are not allowing the client to successfully establish the connection before using the client.

Comment: I see, and I´ve tried doing asychronous function to create the client, but I don´t know how to try it out. I´ve updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
await redisClient.connect();

await redisClient.set('foo', 'bar', (err, reply) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(reply);
});

const value = await redisClient.get('foo', (err, result) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
});
```